# Cannot initialize type '' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have created a class which holds three classes as properties:

```
public class Feeds
{
    public Rentals Rentals { get; set; }
    public Agent Agents { get; set; }
    public NorthwindService.ServiceReference1.File File { get; set; }
}
```

and I am using it like this:

```
var query = from r in ent.Rentals
            join a in ent.Agents on r.ListingAgentID equals a.AgentID
            select new Feeds
            {
                a.AgentID,
                a.Alias,
                a.Bio,
                a.Email,
                a.Fax,
                r.Firstname,
                r.IsStaff,
                r.Languages
            };
```

but I am getting the error:

> Cannot initialize type 'NorthwindService.WebForm1.Feeds' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'  C:\Users\NorthwindService\NorthwindService\WebForm1.aspx.cs

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Your `select` clause doesn't make any sense.  What do you think it does?

Comment: @SLaks I want to select some fields from agents and some from rentals thats why I created Feeds and trying to populate it

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Should be:

```
var query = from r in ent.Rentals
           join a in ent.Agents on r.ListingAgentID equals a.AgentID
           select new Feeds
           {
                    Agents = a,
                    Rentals = r
           }
```

Answer (score 83):

You are using here the collection initializer in C# :

```
new myClass{a,b,c}
```

where myClass is a collection, and a,b,c will be inserted into this collection.

But, the notation you need to use is the object initializer:

```
new myClass{
   myProperty1 = a,
   myProperty2 = b,
   myProperty3 = c
}
```

where the member of a myClass will be initialized. Or maybe you need to use classic constructor and then change your bracket with parenthesis:

```
new myClass(a,b,c)
```

Comment: I think DotnetSparrow is actually trying to use the object initializer, but in the syntax for anonymous types, which will infer the name from the name of the source property. That's not valid when you specify a type. In that case you must also specify the property name.

Comment: Not sure if this answer applies to the question, but it was the solution to my problem.

Comment: This answer saved my day. I was trying to initialize new KeyValuePair<T1,T2>like we do Dictionary.

Comment: I had the same problem and your answer managed to solve it. Thanks!