# filtering results with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

another kinda newbie question I guess. I have EF setup and now I want to select some records based on a filter. I have SomeClass with 4 items (all strings to keep things simple, lets call them string1, string2, and so on). Now, in a post I send the filter in an instance of SomeClass, but maybe not all properties are filled in.
So you might end up with string1="something", string2="bla" and string4="bla2". So string 3 = null. Now, how do I setup the query? If i try something like:

```
var dataset = entities.mydatabase
    .Where(x => x.string1 == someclass.string1 && x.string2 == someclass.string2 && x.string3 == someclass.string3 && x.string4 == someclass.string4)
.Select(x => new { x.string1, x.string2, x.string3, x.string4}).ToList();
```

... I get no results, because string3=null. I could do something with checking all parameters and see if they're set and create the query based on that, but there must be something more elegant than that.

Anyone?

Thanks!
Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return all rows where the `someclass.string` is null **OR** equals to `x.string`.

```
var dataset = entities.mydatabase
    .Where(x => someclass.string1 == null || x.string1 == someclass.string1)
    .Where(x => someclass.string2 == null || x.string2 == someclass.string2)
    .Where(x => someclass.string3 == null || x.string3 == someclass.string3)
    .Where(x => someclass.string4 == null || x.string4 == someclass.string4)
.Select(x => new { x.string1, x.string2, x.string3, x.string4}).ToList();
```

Comment: Brilliant! Simple, just basic SQL (*blush*)

Comment: Another (guess simple one), how do I cast the result to a List<SomeClass>?

Comment: @Ronald Just use the `Select` function to project objects the way you want.. `.Select(x => new SomeClass{ p1 = x.string1, p2 = x.string2 }).ToList()`

Comment: Yeah, got it working! Thanks! Casting is easy, your 'var' is of the right type, no conversions necessary, at least, I serialized it and returned the set, the caller deserialized it to the same class and that's it!

Comment: Your option yields:    Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'zupdeploy.DeployResults' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' H:\DEV\VS2012\zupdeploy\zupdeploy\Controllers\DatabaseController.cs 179 60 zupdeploy

Comment: eh .. ? huh? what's that??

Comment: I cannot guess what's wrong without seeing your code. Post your code in another question, Please.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I

Comment: Guess I should implement the IEnumerable interface in my SomeClass (DeployResults class as you could see). Thanks for your help, I am quite further now.

Comment: @Ronald No, you don't need to implement IEnumerable to project `SomeClass` objects. There's probably something wrong in the way you use the object initializer. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376377) for some hints.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the post. An extra constructor can solve the issue.