# create an object and add a List<string>

Tags: c#

I have a class Category that has:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string catName { get; set; }
public List<string> subCat { get; set; }
```

I want to create a list like this:

```
List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
Category cat = new Category(){ 1 ,"Text", new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three"}};
list.Add(cat);
```

I get red error mark with this error message:

> Cannot initialize type 'Category' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collection.IEnumerable'

Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot initialize type '' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376377/cannot-initialize-type-with-a-collection-initializer-because-it-does-not-impl)

Comment: for new Category, use object initializer syntax. for List<string>, use collection initializer syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By the way you're initializing it, it thinks you're trying to implement a list. Do the following instead.

```
var category = new Category
{
    id = 1,
    catName = "Text",
    subCat = new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three"}
};
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities to accomplish this. Basically your way of thinking is correct, but you have to change it a bit.
One way is to make the constructor with Parameters so if you create an instance of this class it is generated with your Parameters.

```
 List<Category> list = new List<Category>();  
 Category cat = new Category( 1 ,"Text", new List<string>(){"one", "two","three" });  
 list.Add(cat);
```

and as constructor

```
public Category(int  _id, string _name, List<string> _list){  
 id = _id;  
 catName = _name;  
  subCat = _list;
}
```

Or

You add getter and setter methods to your class. Create an object and then set the variables

```
 List<Category> list = new List<Category>();  
 Category cat = new Category();  
 cat.id =  1;  
 cat.catName = "Text";  
 cat.subCat = new List<string>(){"one", "two","three" };  
 list.Add(cat);
```

Comment: Hi hYg-Cain; could you add some context to your answer, for example some explanation of how your code differs from the code in the original question, and what it is about these changes which will provide a solution?

Comment: Sure sorry that i didn't took the time in first place.

Answer (score 2):

Create **object** of Category and assign value

```
Category cat = new Category();
cat.id = 1,
cat.catName = "Text",
cat.subCat = new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three"};

list.Add(cat);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a normal constructor to perform that task? e.g.:

```
public Category(int id, String catName, List<String> subCat){
this.id = id;
this.catName = catName;
this.subCat = subCat;
}
```

use this in your Category class and acces the constructor by simply calling:

```
List<Category> list = new List<Category>();
Category cat = new Category(1, "Text", new List<String>(){"one", "two", "three"});
```

hope this helps you ;)